# para php form y añadir datos con jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, formularios

Tengo un formulario form en php, enviado mediante submit.

Quiero poder parar la ejecución del submit al enviar el formulario, añadir datos con jQuery y seguir con la ejecución sumando los nuevos datos a los del formulario.

```
$('#form_product').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    var formData = $(form).serializeArray();

    var proveedores = [];
    $('#proveedores .proveedor').each(function(){
        var prov = {
            'supplier_id' : $(this).attr('supplier_id'),
            'purchase_price_suplier' : $(this).find('.purchase_price_suplier').html()
        };

        proveedores.push(prov);
    });
    formData.push({'proveedores':proveedores});

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        dataType: "json",
        data: formData
    });
});
```

¿Alguien sabe el problema?.

Gracias.

Comment: Sólo por curiosidad, ¿por qué tienes esta necesidad? Seguro que hay alguna manera mas simple de hacer lo que quieres.

Comment: Estoy utilizando un framework llamado InvoicePlane, esta creado sobre Codeigniter. Todas las páginas tienen su botón de guardar co un formulario estándar de tipo submit. Necesito poder parar la ejecución de ese formulario para poder añadir más datos y que luego siga su proceso. Siempre lo he podido hacer con ajax, pero no entiendo porque ahora no me funciona. Toda la primera parte del código funciona hasta que llega al ajax, hay hace la llamada con los datos del formulario sin coger mis datos añadidos. Pero si hago un console.log de formData si tiene mis datos.....

Comment: Si probe a borrar cookies. Pero nada, solo envía los datos del formulario original (los inputs que tiene), pero no me añade el dato "proveedores" que es el que yo estoy intentando añadir con jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema está aquí. Ya tienes un selector transformado para Jquery. ¿Por qué estás intentando pasar nuevamente el selector a Jquery?

```
var form = $(this);
var formData = $(form).serializeArray();
```

Es como si hicieras

```
var formData = $($(this)).serializeArray();
```

Además no veo la necesidad de guardar el selector `form` puesto que ya no lo usas más adelante, por lo tanto tienes dos opciones:

El selector form sea Javascript y se lo pasas a Jquery para que haga su trabajo

```
var form = this;
var formData = $(form).serializeArray();
```

O pasas directo el selector sin almacenarlo puesto que no lo usas

```
var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
```

El demás código parece bien, entonces con eso te debería funcionar.

**EDITO**
Ya vi donde lo usas. Olvidate de la sugerencia dos.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

@Alberto Siurob no funciona tu solución sigue todo igual. Envía el formulario original, sin las variables añadidas por mi en el jQuery.